# how to make a sentence into a sentence with participle clause?

Tags: participle-clauses

> 1- She comes here, because she needs money.
>   2- She comes here, because needs money.
>   3- She comes here, needing money.
>   4- She comes here, needs money.

Are all the above sentence correct (especially the second one)?

Comment: It's not _she_ that befits, it's the honour of being buried in a cathedral that befits (is appropriate for) someone like her.

Comment: #1 is clearest.  #2 is not English; the verb of the subordinate clause lacks a subject.  #3 does not unambiguously say that her need is her reason for coming; it could be coincidental.